# multiple snackbars overlapping ,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Iam trying to put 3 classes together in  a dashboard.js file , each classes have a snackbar set for 2 sec timeout , the problem is when i load or refresh the dashboard page , the snackbars overlap each other , how do i make it display like a stack ,

---

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
Grid, 
IconButton, 
Typography } from '@mui/material';
import Cards from './cards/Cards';
import ServerStatus from './ServerStatus';
import ServerGroupStatus from './ServerGroupStatus';
import DatabaseStatus from './DatabaseStatus';
import WebServiceStatus from './WebserviceStatus';


export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
       <Cards />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{ marginBottom: '16px' }}>
     </Grid>
      <ServerStatus />
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{ marginBottom: '16px' }}>
     </Grid>
     <ServerGroupStatus />
     <Grid item xs={12} style={{ marginBottom: '16px' }}>
     </Grid>
     <DatabaseStatus />
     <Grid item xs={12} style={{ marginBottom: '16px' }}>
     </Grid>
     <WebServiceStatus />
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

below is how ive implemented the snackbar , ive done the same in all 3 classes

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardContent,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  TableBody,
  Button,
  Snackbar,
  Alert,
  Skeleton
} from '@mui/material';
import { Refresh as RefreshIcon, ZoomIn as ZoomInIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { getServers } from "../api/server-service";
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';


function ServerStatus() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [serverData, setServerData] = useState([]);
  const [snackbarOpen, setSnackbarOpen] = useState(false);
  const [snackbarMessage, setSnackbarMessage] = useState("");
  const [snackbarSeverity, setSnackbarSeverity] = useState("success");

  console.log(theme.palette.primary.main);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchServers();
  }, []);

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchServers();
  };

  const fetchServers = () => {
    getServers()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Server data:", response.data);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setServerData(response.data);
          setLoading(false);
          if (response.data.length > 0) {
            showSnackbar("Successfully fetched all Servers.", "success");
          }
        }, 1000);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        showSnackbar("Error fetching servers: " + error.message, "error");
      });
  };

  const showSnackbar = (message, severity) => {
    setSnackbarMessage(message);
    setSnackbarSeverity(severity);
    setSnackbarOpen(true);
  };

  const handleCloseSnackbar = () => {
    setSnackbarOpen(false);
  };

  const handleZoomInClick = () => {
    console.log('Zoom in clicked');
  };

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Card elevation={3}>
        <CardHeader
          title="Server Status"
          action={
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              startIcon={<RefreshIcon />}
              onClick={handleRefresh}
            >
              Refresh
            </Button>
          }
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Server Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Host</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Active Status</TableCell>
                <TableCell></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {loading ? (
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell colSpan={4}>
                    <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                    <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                    <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                    <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ) : serverData.length === 0 ? (
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell colSpan={4}>Add Monitor Server Request To check status...</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ) : (
                serverData.map((server) => (
                  <TableRow key={server.serverName}>
                    <TableCell>{server.name}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{server.host}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                    <Button
    variant="contained"
    style={{
        backgroundColor: server.isActive ? theme.palette.success.main : theme.palette.error.main,
        color: 'white',
    }}
    disabled={!server.isActive}
>
    {server.isActive ? "Active" : "InActive"}
</Button>




                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <ZoomInIcon
                        onClick={handleZoomInClick}
                        style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>

      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        open={snackbarOpen}
        autoHideDuration={3000}
        onClose={handleCloseSnackbar}
      >
        <Alert onClose={handleCloseSnackbar} severity={snackbarSeverity}>
          {snackbarMessage}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default ServerStatus;
```

i tried changing the position  , still same , it overlaps

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642607/reactmaterial-ui-multiple-snackbar<br>
Possible duplicate

Comment: thanks , but iam calling those 3 classes  , in dashboard.js class ,  even notistack doesnt work

Comment: if i try to add all 3 codes in dashboard.js file 
notistack works , but the code is very huge , its unorganized